# Select data from array with indexes

Tags: postgresql

I have an array ARRAY[10,20,30,40,50,60] and another array with of indexes ARRAY[1,2,3]
I would like to create a sql query to get values with index array.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM ARRAY[10,20,30,40,50,60] WHERE <index> = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

Output of this query would be:

```
[20, 30, 40];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, the array element index starts from 1, not 0.

You may do `UNNEST` of the main array with `ORDINALITY` and then use it in the `where` clause.

```
select array_agg(elem order by idx) from 
   unnest (ARRAY[10,20,30,40,50,60])
             with ordinality as a(elem,idx)
         where idx = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

this yields `{10,20,30}`

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8b0bb19896abf75c0e8c5f96273b5693)

Comment: OMG, you are legend! Thank you